# R Rowise operation on partially similar columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df with multiple instances of each column. I'd like to "concatenate" all rows for each group of column. Possibly with dplyr if that's possible.

Example:

| IDs | p001_i1 | p001_i2 | p501_i1 | p501_i2 | p501_i3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | NA | NA | 1 | NA | NA |
| AB | 5 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| AC | NA | 10 | NA | NA | 2 |

Here for example I'd like to group the columns with similar starting name (here "p001" and "p501" but there can be many more, and different numbers of instances for each "pxxx" (p001 has 2 columns, p501 has 3)) and report their non-missing value for each row.
The final result would be:

| IDs | p001 | p501 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | NA | 1 |
| AB | 5 | NA |
| AC | 10 | 2 |

If there's multiple values for each row, it could for example get the mean or the value of the latest field (ie priority i3 > i2 > i1).

I've looked at across(), c_across() and pmap(), but I can't see how to implement that on each "group" of columns. Thanks!

Comment: *"get the mean or the value of the latest field (ie priority i3 > i2 > i1)"* So which one is it? The mean *or* the last value?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(
        -IDs, names_pattern = c("(.+)_(.+)"), names_to = c("name", NA)) %>%
    group_by(IDs, name) %>%
    summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
    pivot_wider()
## A tibble: 3 × 3
#  IDs    p001  p501
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 AA      NaN     1
#2 AB        5   NaN
#3 AC       10     2
```

Explanation: Reshape from wide to long (and only retain the first part of the wide column names `"p001"`, `"p501"` through using `names_pattern` and `names_to`), group by `IDs` and `name`, then calculate the mean (ignoring `NA`s) and reshape again from long to wide.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <-read.table(text = "IDs p001_i1 p001_i2 p501_i1 p501_i2 p501_i3
AA  NA  NA  1   NA  NA
AB  5   NA  NA  NA  NA
AC  NA  10  NA  NA  2", header  =T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` option, but this preserves separate groups for the `AC` column:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  group_by(IDs, name_prefix = str_extract(name, "^.+?(?=_)")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name_prefix, values_from = value, values_fill = NA) %>%
  select(-name)


# A tibble: 4 × 3
  IDs    p501  p001
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 AA        1    NA
2 AB       NA     5
3 AC       NA    10
4 AC        2    NA
```

Also, you can check this out:

[How to get value of last non-NA column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785827/how-to-get-value-of-last-non-na-column)